# Storing multiple items in C array

Tags: c, arrays

What would be a best and simple way of storing incoming message from different processes in an array in C? I was thinking to have an array MQ but also need to store message sequence numbers and process ids for each incoming message. Thanks.

Comment: Is the question concerning how to store the data or how to do it threadsafe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have an array of structures that contain the various elements that you want to store, e.g.

```
struct MessageInfo {
  int message_id;
  pid_t incoming_pid;
  char message_data[MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
};

struct MessageInfo message_queue[MAX_QUEUE_LEN];
```

Comment: Yeah, depends if he is asking about the actually structure or about thread safety part.